# Microphone is not working | Zenbook model ux32la codec Conexant CX20751/2 | ALSA | ubuntu 20.04

Tags: pulseaudio, microphone

I saw many other threads about **microphone not working** and I studied all of them. It is such common bug / issue with microphones using **Ubuntu**. There are many patches and quirks to fix the problem, However not for any model. **I tried all solutions from other posts without success.** So, basically I' m writing this post, in small hope deep inside that someone can help me, but anyway, for someone specialized enough to maybe in the feature give patches / quirks / updates for such models as well. :(

However if there are any good soul who can help me or have bright ideas, I will gladly make all of them and be happy fix this problem!

Below screens and data about specialization and what I've done:

System Information:

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
KERNEL: 5.4.0-40-generic
```

**Sources_list:** pacmd list-sources

```
pacmd list-sources
2 source(s) available.
    index: 0
        name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor>
        driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
        flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
        state: IDLE
        suspend cause: (none)
        priority: 1030
        volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
                balance 0,00
        base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
        volume steps: 65537
        muted: no
        current latency: 0,00 ms
        max rewind: 4 KiB
        sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
        channel map: front-left,front-right
                     Stereo
        used by: 0
        linked by: 0
        configured latency: 371,52 ms; range is 0,50 .. 371,52 ms
        monitor_of: 0
        card: 1 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0>
        module: 8
        properties:
                device.description = "Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
                device.class = "monitor"
                alsa.card = "1"
                alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
                alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7d18000 irq 48"
                alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
                device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
                sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1"
                device.bus = "pci"
                device.vendor.id = "8086"
                device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
                device.product.id = "9c20"
                device.product.name = "8 Series HD Audio Controller"
                device.form_factor = "internal"
                device.string = "1"
                module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
  * index: 1
        name: <alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo>
        driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
        flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
        state: SUSPENDED
        suspend cause: IDLE
        priority: 9039
        volume: front-left: 66847 / 102% / 0,52 dB,   front-right: 66847 / 102% / 0,52 dB
                balance 0,00
        base volume: 13076 /  20% / -42,00 dB
        volume steps: 65537
        muted: no
        current latency: 0,00 ms
        max rewind: 0 KiB
        sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
        channel map: front-left,front-right
                     Stereo
        used by: 0
        linked by: 0
        configured latency: 0,00 ms; range is 0,50 .. 371,52 ms
        card: 1 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0>
        module: 8
        properties:
                alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
                device.api = "alsa"
                device.class = "sound"
                alsa.class = "generic"
                alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
                alsa.name = "CX20751/2 Analog"
                alsa.id = "CX20751/2 Analog"
                alsa.subdevice = "0"
                alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
                alsa.device = "0"
                alsa.card = "1"
                alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
                alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7d18000 irq 48"
                alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
                device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
                sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1"
                device.bus = "pci"
                device.vendor.id = "8086"
                device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
                device.product.id = "9c20"
                device.product.name = "8 Series HD Audio Controller"
                device.form_factor = "internal"
                device.string = "front:1"
                device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
                device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
                device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
                device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
                device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
                device.description = "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
                module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
        ports:
                analog-input-internal-mic: Internal Microphone (priority 8900, latency offset 35000 usec, available: unknown)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
                analog-input-mic: Microphone (priority 8700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        active port: <analog-input-internal-mic>
```

**Sinks List:** pacmd list-sinks

```
witek@witek-UX32LA ~
└─ $ pacmd list-sinks  
1 sink(s) available.
  * index: 0
        name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo>
        driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
        flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
        state: RUNNING
        suspend cause: (none)
        priority: 9039
        volume: front-left: 29489 /  45% / -20,81 dB,   front-right: 29489 /  45% / -20,81 dB
                balance 0,00
        base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
        volume steps: 65537
        muted: no
        current latency: 19,23 ms
        max request: 4 KiB
        max rewind: 4 KiB
        monitor source: 0
        sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
        channel map: front-left,front-right
                     Stereo
        used by: 1
        linked by: 5
        configured latency: 23,22 ms; range is 0,50 .. 371,52 ms
        card: 1 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0>
        module: 8
        properties:
                alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
                device.api = "alsa"
                device.class = "sound"
                alsa.class = "generic"
                alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
                alsa.name = "CX20751/2 Analog"
                alsa.id = "CX20751/2 Analog"
                alsa.subdevice = "0"
                alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
                alsa.device = "0"
                alsa.card = "1"
                alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
                alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7d18000 irq 48"
                alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
                device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
                sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1"
                device.bus = "pci"
                device.vendor.id = "8086"
                device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
                device.product.id = "9c20"
                device.product.name = "8 Series HD Audio Controller"
                device.form_factor = "internal"
                device.string = "front:1"
                device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
                device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
                device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
                device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
                device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
                device.description = "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
                module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
        ports:
                analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
                analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
        active port: <analog-output-speaker>
```

**ALSAMIXER:**
[Codec Alsamixer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XilF2.png)

**hdjackretask:**
[hdjackretask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJ0rX.png)

**Pavucontrol:**

[Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rq78o.png)

[input devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StTtI.png)

[output devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPOAv.png)

I tried:

1. configured /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base in many different ways:

```
sudo subl /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base
```

added this

```
options snd-hda-intel model=asus-zenbook
```

and this

```
options snd-hda-intel model=MODEL position_fix=1
```

and this

```
options snd-hda-intel model=OTHER MODELS SUCH AS DELL
```

all of this without success

2. I connected external microphone via jack / headset and this external microphone didn't work as well
3. I connected external microphone via bluetooth ( phone as microphone ) using app wo mic and managed to record some poor quality audio. However it did record.

Thats what I've done.

Greetings and appreciate all help!

Answer (score 0):

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1875989

```
sudo apt-get remove timidity
```

solved my issue with CX20751/2 too.

Comment: unfortunatly, I don't even have this installed.